# how to retrive the BTLE peripherals when user manually quit app from background?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, btle

Explanation :

I am connecting to BTLE peripheral using core bluetooth framework, saving the peripheral identifier in a database.
At the same time, I am saving the peripherals in an array to handle reconnection with peripherals.
But, when user manually quit the app, my array becomes empty.
 due to which I won't be able to reconnect those peripherals again.

Now, I have peripherals identifiers in my database. 
I have read about it and found that there is a delegate method

```
- (NSArray<CBPeripheral *> *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray<NSUUID *> *)identifiers NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0)
```

To get the peripherals but it returns nothing.
How I can get the peripherals again?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation//NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithA

I also check above document. In that they mentioned about the methods to reconnect to the peripherals

```
Retrieving a List of Known Peripherals

The first time you discover a peripheral, the system generates an identifier (a UUID, represented by an NSUUID object) to identify the peripheral. You can then store this identifier (using, for instance, the resources of the NSUserDefaults class), and later use it to try to reconnect to the peripheral using the retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: method of the CBCentralManager class. The following describes one way to use this method to reconnect to a peripheral you’ve previously connected to.

When your app launches, call the retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: method, passing in an array containing the identifiers of the peripherals you’ve previously discovered and connected to (and whose identifiers you have saved), like this:

    knownPeripherals =
        [myCentralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:savedIdentifiers];
The central manager tries to match the identifiers you provided to the identifiers of previously discovered peripherals and returns the results as an array of CBPeripheral objects. If no matches are found, the array is empty and you should try one of the other two reconnection options. If the array is not empty, let the user select (in the UI) which peripheral to try to reconnect to.

When the user selects a peripheral, try to connect to it by calling the connectPeripheral:options: method of the CBCentralManager class. If the peripheral device is still available to be connected to, the central manager calls the centralManager:didConnectPeripheral: method of its delegate object and the peripheral device is successfully reconnected.

Note: A peripheral device may not be available to be connected to for a few reasons. For instance, the device may not be in the vicinity of the central. In addition, some Bluetooth low energy devices use a random device address that changes periodically. Therefore, even if the device is nearby, the address of the device may have changed since the last time it was discovered by the system, in which case the CBPeripheral object you are trying to connect to doesn’t correspond to the actual peripheral device. If you cannot reconnect to the peripheral because its address has changed, you must rediscover it using the scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: method.
```

Comment: If `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` doesn't return a peripheral then you will need to discover the peripheral by scanning for its advertisement.

Comment: Doesn't is make more sense to store the UUID on a local database and retrieve it from your background thread

Comment: Yes Daniel , but how you will retrive them. as I have used retrive peripheral method and passed the identifiers to it. but still i didn't get those peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

On application startup I would just discover all the peripherals and then compare discovered peripherals with the peripheral identifiers stored in the database.

After the comparison of the discovered peripherals and peripherals, the connections for desired peripherals can be made.

Comment: Hi Lipponen, I am also thinking the same. but will be interested if there is any other solution.

Comment: Why would you want another solution? Just write your array to database on every moment it's updated, and repopulate your array from database when it's empty and datase is not empty.

Comment: We save peripherals Identifier in a database, but we don't have the peripherals object for communication with BLE's. So need a way to get the peripherals from identifiers.

Comment: `CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` is how you do that, but only if the central still knows about them. Often it does, but in this case it doesn't, so you need to rediscover them. The page you linked to gives the flow. It's all about what is or isn't cached. It's not possible to go in every case from "I have an identifier" to "I have a CBPeripheral" in one step. Sometimes yes, but sometimes no, and you just have to code for that. Peripherals generally keep their identifier for a while, but there's no promise of that, either. Same peripheral may have new identifier.